# Why virtual product is not available to buy on Magento 2.3.1?

Tags: magento, magento2

I created a virtual product but despite I have enabled it and set as "In stock" I can't add to the cart because I see the message "Notify me when it will be available".

What else I could check to solve this problem?

Comment: try rebuilding the stock index